# Catching Cross Domain JS Errors in IE11

Tags: javascript, cors, internet-explorer-11

By default JS errors originating on different domains aren't passed to `window.onerror` handler - Although I don't think this happens on versions of IE below 10 (or maybe 11). Instead they get just a basic `"Script Error" on Line 0` message.

In most browsers you have to set `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute on the script and return CORS headers on the script and then these errors will be caught.

However this doesn't seem to work on IE11. Is a different technique required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback Kevin. IE does not currently support the crossOrigin attribute but it is something that is on our backlog.